# Hive SQL : Find the longest continuous sequence start and end point

Tags: sql, hive, sequence

I have an example dataset below

| id | rowid | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 1 |

`rowid` is auto increased by id. I need to find the longest continuous sequence of rowid partitioned by id, and then find the start and end rowid for this sequence.

Excepted output for this example data

| id | start_id | end_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 5 |

Updated:
I found out how to find the first and last points.
Find the end point

```sql
-- Find the end point
select * from (select * from tbl where status = 1) t1 
left join (select * from tbl where status = 1) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.rowid = t2.rowid + 1
where t2.rowid is null
;
-- Find the start point
select * from (select * from tbl where status = 1) t1 
left join (select * from tbl where status = 1) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.rowid = t2.rowid - 1
where t2.rowid is null
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a litter complicated to get the result with sql for this question.

I have some idea share with you.

step 1, get max continuous sequence count.

```sql
select t1.id, max(counter) as max_counter from(
select t.id,gap, count(1) as counter from (
select id, rowid,rowid - row_number() over(partition by id order by rowid) as gap  from table1 
where status = 1)t group by id, gap)t1 group BY t1.id
```

the result like

```
id, max_counter
1,3
2,4
3,3
```

The next step need to use the result to join  the intermediate result of this sql.
Hope someone can complement this answser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I learned how to get the first and last point for the sequence. The post is updated.